# $x² + y² +6y = 7$ to polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

How do i come from $M1$ to the polar coordinates?

$$M1 \qquad x^2 + y^2 +6y = 7$$

I started with:

$$r^2 * (\cos^2\varphi + \sin^2\varphi)+ 6r\sin\varphi = 7$$
because:
$$(\cos^2\varphi + \sin^2\varphi) = 1 $$
means that:

$$r^2 + 6r\sin\varphi = 7$$

But how do I get $r$ on one side? And what are the possible values of $\varphi$? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the quadratic $r^2-6r\sin\varphi-7=0$
$$
r=-3\sin\varphi+\sqrt{7+9\sin^2\varphi}
$$
Why only $+$? Because that equation has only one positive root, because of the negative constant term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But could you please explain it in more steps how you got to $r$? Thanks

Comment: @user2724695 Its a quadratic equation in the unknown $r$, so I used the usual formula for $ax^2+bx+c=0$, with $x=r$, $a=1$, $b=-6\sin\varphi$ and $c=-7$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your equation is equivalent to $x^2+(y+3)^2=16$, which is a circle of radius $4$ and center $(0,-3)$